# Connection Pooling

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, connection-pooling

I have the following code, If I use conn == null in finally do I still use connection pooling? 
I know it is a good practice to close your connection but how about disposing the whole connection object?

```
    public void ExecuteNonQuery(SqlCommand Cmd)
    {
        //========== Connection ==========//
        SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(strConStr);

        try
        {
            //========== Open Connection ==========//
            Conn.Open();

            //========== Execute Command ==========//
            Cmd.Connection = Conn;
            Cmd.CommandTimeout = 180;
            Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception Exc)
        {
            throw Exc;
        }
        finally
        {
            //======== Closing Connection ========//
            if (Conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            { Conn.Close(); }

            //======== Disposing object ========//
            Conn = null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just a few points to explain the "why" of some of the answers you're getting... `throw Exc` will replace the exception's stack trace, making it hard to debug. You can just write `throw` instead, or leave the catch out entirely. `Conn = null` effectively does nothing, you are looking for `Conn.Dispose()` i think (which will handle closing). And the `using()` block is just shorthand for try/finally/dispose - great way to cut down on LOC...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, consider using `using`, second, let the framework handle disposal. The [managed providers](http://ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/2004/02/09/connpool.html) will do pooling based on the connection string.

```
public void ExecuteNonQuery(SqlCommand Cmd) 
{ 
    //========== Connection ==========// 
    using(SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(strConStr))
    { 
        //========== Open Connection ==========// 
        Conn.Open(); 

        //========== Execute Command ==========// 
        Cmd.Connection = Conn; 
        Cmd.CommandTimeout = 180; 
        Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

- You don't need to set anything to null or nothing in .NET.  That is handled automatically by the [Garbage Collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0xy59wtx.aspx).
- It is imperative that you **call Conn.Dispose()** in both your error handling and also if everything goes as planned.  The Try Catch Finally block is great for this.  Another alternative is to use the **[Using](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334521/usage-of-a-using-statement/2334604#2334604)** keyword when declaring your connection, so that the Connection object will be properly disposed of whatever happens.
- Don't worry about pooling your connections.  If you open a new one every time you need to use one, this is fine.  ADO.NET pools connections for you behind the scenes.  There is a minor performance if you reuse the same open connection object, but to keep things simple don't worry about it.

You could do the same with the following code.  The result would be the same.  Whether it errors off or not, `Conn` will be handled properly.  Any error will percolate up, as before.

```
public void ExecuteNonQuery(SqlCommand Cmd)
{
    Using (SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(strConStr));
    {
        //========== Open Connection ==========//
        Conn.Open();

        //========== Execute Command ==========//
        Cmd.Connection = Conn;
        Cmd.CommandTimeout = 180;
        Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

As you can see, when the only error handling you want/need is to make sure your Connection Objects are disposed of properly, the Using syntax can make things tidy.

Comment: Thanks your post was also helpful. I am not sure i can mark multiple reply as answer.

Comment: You can only have one "accepted answer", and would have to deselect one to choose another.  If you settle on another, no worries!  You certainly want to upvote anyone who made a good attempt to help you of course, once you can (you have to have 15 I think).  Welcome to Stackoverflow.  As you can see, a great place to get help!

Answer (score 0):

Setting it to null is redundant as it will go out of scope anyway at the end of the function.  Yes, you are still using connection pooling if you do so.

Comment: but without "closing" (relinquishing) the connection, you could quickly run out of connections in the pool

Answer (score 0):

You can dispose your object and still use pooling.

And also ff its

1. A Managed application
2. Is a webapplication
3. Has heavy traffic

Then disposing of the object will do you a great favor as the garbagecollector usually won't keep up enough to save you performance.