# How does the CLR find the classes which implement IDisposable?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, idisposable

I need some clarification on…

1. … how the CLR — more specifically, the garbage collector — finds the classes which implement the `IDisposable` interface; and
2. … how it calls the `Dispose` method (of all classes which implement the `IDisposable` interface) to free up memory?

Comment: I think you should read a bit more about IDisposable, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12368/how-to-dispose-a-class-in-net - IDisposable has nothing to do with freeing up memory, nor does GC run it at all. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/732864/finalize-vs-dispose

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen: Thanks for links

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The CLR does not call Dispose(), this is up to user code to call either directly or through the use of the `using` statement. The CLR will however call [finalizers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.finalize%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), although this is not gauranteed.

Comment: The CLR **might** call finalizers. There is no guarantee it really does.

Comment: Is it not guaranteed the finalizers will be called before the application quits?

Comment: @koumides The application may end abruptly for example, in which case finalizers may not run. The link in my answer gives detail.

Answer (score 1):

`Dispose` is not called automatically. The compiler generates calls to `Dispose` when you write `using`, or call `Dispose` directly.

Comment: In this case why we need to implement IDisposable method, instead we can create any method which will free the resource. Even 'using' also expanding with try...finally() where it calls Dispose method. We can also do the same without implementing IDisposable interface. The answer for this will explain the need of interface I guess.

Comment: @Syed I don't understand that comment.

Comment: From your answer what I'm understanding is we need to explicitly call the Dispose method. My doubt is, then why we need to implement IDisposable interface and then Dispose method, we can directly write any other method which is freeing the resource.

Comment: @Syed You are at liberty to write your own method, named however you like, and call it to free the resource. However, you will miss out on a number of important features, not least the ability to write `using`.

Comment: I agreed sir, then my point is why we need interfaces. I think I am missing something. Even 'using' also expanding to try...finally() block and in finally block it is calling Dispose method.

Comment: The design uses interfaces because that is the natural way to allow classes to implement optional functionality. Think about an alternative and see if you can find a better one?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2290/discussion-between-syed-and-david-heffernan)