# Why to set an object to Nothing in the Finally block?

Tags: vb.net, object, try-catch-finally

In this VB.NET code:

```
Dim o as SomeClass
Try
   o = new SomeClass
   'call some method on o here
Catch(...)
   ...
Finally
   o = Nothing
End Try
```

Why is there a need to set o to `Nothing`? What if i don't set it to `Nothing` in the `Finally` block? What i think is that it is OK if you don't set it to `Nothing` because the object will be marked for GC.

Comment: If SomeClass has a .Dispose method, you should use that:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12368/how-to-dispose-a-class-in-net

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling null on a class vs Dispose()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574019/calling-null-on-a-class-vs-dispose) (Ignore the fact that the top-rated answer is in C#. It's exactly the same for VB.NET. Setting an object to `Nothing` is *completely superfluous* in VB.NET. Note that's different from the COM-based versions of VB like VB 6.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the object is unsafe to use out of the try catch should this be done. If this was a stream for example you'd see the stream closed and then set to nothing. It is not always the right thing to do but this code is seen a lot.

consider this code

```
Sub Main()
    Dim o As String
    Try
        o = "Hello"
        Console.Out.WriteLine("hi {0}", o)
    Catch ex As Exception
        ' do something here
    Finally
        o = Nothing
    End Try

    ' unable to do something here
End Sub
```

Allthough it is a silly example it does mean you cannot reference o outside now because it is no longer set to an instance of an object. That is why it is done by a lot of people. If you are in a function and a function ends at that point there is no need to set to Nothing as the object falls out of scope however lots of people will set stuff to `Nothing` out of habit **I'd consider that incorrect and bad code design**

Comment: Does that mean, as a practice, i should set all objects to `Nothing` once i am done with them?

Comment: @badmaash: No. As krystan said "If the object is unsafe to use" only. The vast majority of the time it is not needed.

Comment: Any class that's correctly designed will throw an exception if you try to use it after it has been disposed. It's superfluous to set it to `Nothing`. And I'd argue it's a bad pattern to get into because people think it actually does something. It just adds noise to your code. And, as you mention, if the class *is* poorly designed such that it *doesn't* throw an exception upon improper usage, you should definitely use scoping to your advantage. A `Using` statement is the easiest thing, but you can also wrap it in a new function.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the object is not safe to use outside the the try.. catch.. finally block. It's not guaranteed it's in a consistent state, so it's set to Nothing to make it obvious t's not supposed to be used.

Comment: Actually. no. That's a holdover from VB6 and COM days, when setting to `Nothing` actually decremented the reference count on the object.